How does the change in the number of member variables of a callable class map to the assembly of a function calling it?
Consider this TU:
struct Foo {
    int operator()(int) const;
};

int foo(Foo b) {
    return b(17);
}

It will compile to:
foo(Foo):
  sub rsp, 24
  mov esi, 17
  lea rdi, [rsp+15]
  call Foo::operator()(int) const
  add rsp, 24
  ret

whereas if the class contains, say, 6 int members, like this,
struct Baz {
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int u;
    int v;
    int z;
    int operator()(int) const;
};

then the same foo as above will compile down to
baz(Baz):
  sub rsp, 8
  mov esi, 17
  lea rdi, [rsp+16]
  call Baz::operator()(int) const
  add rsp, 8
  ret

How do I map the difference in the assembly to the difference in the C++ code?

Your assembly listing is muddled by the compiler passing the fields of Baz partially in registers and partially via the stack. If you take Foo and Baz by reference the calling code will be identical.

The difference in assembly is not due to how operator() is called, but how the object is passed by value to the calling function, foo or baz. In other words, what's different is figuring out the this pointer of the object before calling its method. The different offsets relative to rsp are because Foo and Baz occupy different amounts of space on the stack.

sub rsp, 24 vs sub rsp, 8 difference reflects different stack requirements.

With more than 16 bytes of members, x86-64 System V passes it on the stack, so baz can just pass a pointer to its stack arg as the this pointer for operator().  (Since it doesn't need to keep an unmodified copy.)  C++ member functions have T* this as their first arg, so that's the LEA into RDI with the first "normal" arg going in the second arg-passing slot, RSI.  (Actually ESI since int is 32-bit in this ABI.)
(Fun fact: Windows x64 passes larger objects by pointer, so every arg fits in an 8-byte stack (or reg) slot.)
With zero members, there are no register args to spill, so foo just passes a pointer to 1 byte of stack space it reserved itself.  (Note the sub rsp,24 reserving 16 more bytes than needed instead of just using some of the 8 bytes it had to reserve to maintain RSP % 16 == 0 alignment before a call pushes an 8-byte return address.  This is is a longstanding GCC missed optimization.)
With a size between 1 and 16 bytes (and still no copy-constructor or destructor which would get the C++ ABI to pass it in memory), you'd see code to dump the incoming RDI (and maybe RSI depending on size) to the stack and pass a pointer to that.
struct Bar {
    int i[2];
    int operator()(int) const;
};
int bar(Bar b) {
    return b(17);
}

Godbolt
bar(Bar):
        sub     rsp, 24                   # reserve space
        mov     esi, 17
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], rdi    # store incoming register arg to memory
        lea     rdi, [rsp+8]              # pass a pointer to it as Bar* this
        call    Bar::operator()(int) const
        add     rsp, 24
        ret

